# Count frequency of words in a list and sort by frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, frequency

I am using Python 3.3

I need to create two lists, one for the unique words and the other for the frequencies of the word.

I have to sort the unique word list based on the frequencies list so that the word with the highest frequency is first in the list.

I have the design in text but am uncertain how to implement it in Python.

The methods I have found so far use either `Counter` or dictionaries which we have not learned. I have already created the list from the file containing all the words but do not know how to find the frequency of each word in the list. I know I will need a loop to do this but cannot figure it out.

Here's the basic design:

```
 original list = ["the", "car",....]
 newlst = []
 frequency = []
 for word in the original list
       if word not in newlst:
           newlst.append(word)
           set frequency = 1
       else
           increase the frequency
 sort newlst based on frequency list
```

Comment: it's hard for us to know what you know.  Have you learned `set`?  the `count` method of lists?  etc.  Bound the problem in meaningful terms.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use things you haven't been taught? Is learning ahead discouraged these days?

Comment: A [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be a fairly efficient alternative. You can build one with just lists

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 199):

use this

```
from collections import Counter
list1=['apple','egg','apple','banana','egg','apple']
counts = Counter(list1)
print(counts)
# Counter({'apple': 3, 'egg': 2, 'banana': 1})
```

Comment: stellar solution

Comment: Still robust in 2021, way to go.

Answer (score 55):

You can use

```
from collections import Counter
```

It supports Python 2.7，read more information [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

1.

```
>>>c = Counter('abracadabra')
>>>c.most_common(3)
[('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

use dict

```
>>>d={1:'one', 2:'one', 3:'two'}
>>>c = Counter(d.values())
[('one', 2), ('two', 1)]
```

But, You have to read the file first, and converted to dict.

2.
it's the python docs example,use re and Counter

```
# Find the ten most common words in Hamlet
>>> import re
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('hamlet.txt').read().lower())
>>> Counter(words).most_common(10)
[('the', 1143), ('and', 966), ('to', 762), ('of', 669), ('i', 631),
 ('you', 554),  ('a', 546), ('my', 514), ('hamlet', 471), ('in', 451)]
```

Answer (score 20):

```
words = file("test.txt", "r").read().split() #read the words into a list.
uniqWords = sorted(set(words)) #remove duplicate words and sort
for word in uniqWords:
    print words.count(word), word
```

Comment: A great pythonian way!

Comment: have you test the code with large file? If the file is too large, it will cost lot of time. collection is more efficient.

Comment: This is inferior to `Counter`. You needlessly throw away the counts when you do `set(words)`, so then every time you need the counts you have to look each up with `words.count(word)`, which will be inefficient esp. for large texts.

Answer (score 13):

Pandas answer:

```
import pandas as pd
original_list = ["the", "car", "is", "red", "red", "red", "yes", "it", "is", "is", "is"]
pd.Series(original_list).value_counts()
```

If you wanted it in ascending order instead, it is as simple as:

```
pd.Series(original_list).value_counts().sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

Yet another solution with another algorithm without using collections:

```
def countWords(A):
   dic={}
   for x in A:
       if not x in  dic:        #Python 2.7: if not dic.has_key(x):
          dic[x] = A.count(x)
   return dic

dic = countWords(['apple','egg','apple','banana','egg','apple'])
sorted_items=sorted(dic.items())   # if you want it sorted
```

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to make a list of lists, with each sub-list in the new list containing a word and a count:

```
list1 = []    #this is your original list of words
list2 = []    #this is a new list

for word in list1:
    if word in list2:
        list2.index(word)[1] += 1
    else:
        list2.append([word,0])
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
for word in list1:
    try:
        list2.index(word)[1] += 1
    except:
        list2.append([word,0])
```

This would be less efficient than using a dictionary, but it uses more basic concepts.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reduce() - A functional way.

```
words = "apple banana apple strawberry banana lemon"
reduce( lambda d, c: d.update([(c, d.get(c,0)+1)]) or d, words.split(), {})
```

returns:

```
{'strawberry': 1, 'lemon': 1, 'apple': 2, 'banana': 2}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Counter would be the best way, but if you don't want to do that, you can implement it yourself this way.

```
# The list you already have
word_list = ['words', ..., 'other', 'words']
# Get a set of unique words from the list
word_set = set(word_list)
# create your frequency dictionary
freq = {}
# iterate through them, once per unique word.
for word in word_set:
    freq[word] = word_list.count(word) / float(len(word_list))
```

freq will end up with the frequency of each word in the list you already have.

You need `float` in there to convert one of the integers to a float, so the resulting value will be a float.

Edit:

If you can't use a dict or set, here is another less efficient way:

```
# The list you already have
word_list = ['words', ..., 'other', 'words']
unique_words = []
for word in word_list:
    if word not in unique_words:
        unique_words += [word]
word_frequencies = []
for word in unique_words:
    word_frequencies += [float(word_list.count(word)) / len(word_list)]
for i in range(len(unique_words)):
    print(unique_words[i] + ": " + word_frequencies[i])
```

The indicies of `unique_words` and `word_frequencies` will match.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way is to use a dictionary that maps a word to it's count. But if you can't use that, you might want to use 2 lists - 1 storing the words, and the other one storing counts of words. Note that order of words and counts matters here. Implementing this would be hard and not very efficient.

Comment: It turns out I have to do the hard way so I need two lists. I have the words stored but not sure how to store the frequencies in a way that I will be able to sort the word list based on the frequency list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code support your question
is_char() check for validate string count those strings alone, Hashmap is dictionary in python

```
def is_word(word):
   cnt =0
   for c in word:

      if 'a' <= c <='z' or 'A' <= c <= 'Z' or '0' <= c <= '9' or c == '$':
          cnt +=1
   if cnt==len(word):
      return True
  return False

def words_freq(s):
  d={}
  for i in s.split():
    if is_word(i):
        if i in d:
            d[i] +=1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
   return d

 print(words_freq('the the sky$ is blue not green'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way

```
d = {}
l = ['Hi','Hello','Hey','Hello']
for a in l:
    d[a] = l.count(a)
print(d)
Output : {'Hi': 1, 'Hello': 2, 'Hey': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
words = []
freqs = []

for line in sorted(original list): #takes all the lines in a text and sorts them
    line = line.rstrip() #strips them of their spaces
    if line not in words: #checks to see if line is in words
        words.append(line) #if not it adds it to the end words
        freqs.append(1) #and adds 1 to the end of freqs
    else:
        index = words.index(line) #if it is it will find where in words
        freqs[index] += 1 #and use the to change add 1 to the matching index in freqs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in original_list:
   words_dict[word] = words_dict.get(word,0) + 1

sorted_dt = {key: value for key, value in sorted(words_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

keys = list(sorted_dt.keys())
values = list(sorted_dt.values())
print(keys)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

word and frequency if you need

```
def counter_(input_list_):
  lu = []
  for v in input_list_:
    ele = (v, lc.count(v)/len(lc)) #if you don't % remove <</len(lc)>>
    if ele not in lu:
      lu.append(ele)
  return lu

counter_(['a', 'n', 'f', 'a'])
```

output:

```
[('a', 0.5), ('n', 0.25), ('f', 0.25)]
```

Answer (score -1):

the best thing to do is :

```
def wordListToFreqDict(wordlist):
    wordfreq = [wordlist.count(p) for p in wordlist]
    return dict(zip(wordlist, wordfreq))
```

then try to : 
           `wordListToFreqDict(originallist)`

Comment: This is hardly the "best" way to do this. You only need to do a single pass on the text to count the frequency of words, whereas here you do a pass for every unique word.

Comment: It doesn't even add the constraint for each unique word.