# python position frequency dictionary of letters in words

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, frequency, letter

To efficiently get the frequencies of letters (given alphabet `ABC` in a dictionary in a string `code` I can make a function a-la (Python 3) :

```
def freq(code):
   return{n: code.count(n)/float(len(code)) for n in 'ABC'}
```

Then

```
code='ABBBC'   
freq(code)
```

Gives me

```
{'A': 0.2, 'C': 0.2, 'B': 0.6}
```

But how can I get the frequencies for each position along a list of strings of unequal lengths ? For instance `mcode=['AAB', 'AA', 'ABC', '']` should give me a nested structure like a list of dict (where each dict is the frequency per position):

```
[{'A': 1.0, 'C': 0.0, 'B': 0.0}, 
 {'A': 0.66, 'C': 0.0, 'B': 0.33},
 {'A': 0.0, 'C': 0.5, 'B': 0.5}]
```

I cannot figure out how to do the frequencies per position across all strings, and wrap this in a list comprehension. Inspired by other SO for word counts e.g.  the well discussed post [Python: count frequency of words in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510768/python-count-frequency-of-words-in-a-list) I believed maybe the Counter module from `collections`  might be a help.

Understand it like this - write the mcode strings on separate lines:

```
AAB
AA
ABC
```

Then what I need is the column-wise frequencies (AAA, AAB, BC) of the alphabet ABC in a list of dict where each list element is the frequencies of ABC per columns.

Comment: I don't quite understand your example. Should the output for first string 'AAB' be {'A': 0.66, 'C': 0.0, 'B': 0.33}? Also, is there always a max of 3 distinct letters in your strings (ABC)?

Comment: The first position in the frequencies are to calculated on AAA, at postition 2 its AAB at postiion 3 its BC. Does that make sense ? Align words on seperate lines, then find frequencies along columns.

Comment: You could do `itertools.zip_longest(*mcode)` and loop with your `freq` over this. You have to change `len(code)` to reflect the correct length though.

Comment: BTW: in Python 3 you don't need the `float()`.

Comment: @Allen Do you understand it better now ? - see my update (I wrote it was the frequency at each position )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much shorter solution:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def freq(code):
    l = len(code) - code.count(None)
    return {n: code.count(n)/l for n in 'ABC'}

mcode=['AAB', 'AA', 'ABC', '']
results = [ freq(code) for code in zip_longest(*mcode) ]
print(results)
```

Comment: Thats very nice - I always forget about itertools

Answer (score 1):

Example, the steps are shortly explained in comments. `Counter` of module `collections` is not used, because the mapping for a position also contains characters, that are not present at this position and the order of frequencies does not seem to matter.

```python
def freq(*words):
    # All dictionaries contain all characters as keys, even
    # if a characters is not present at a position.
    # Create a sorted list of characters in chars.
    chars = set()
    for word in words:
        chars |= set(word)

    chars = sorted(chars)

    # Get the number of positions.
    max_position = max(len(word) for word in words)

    # Initialize the result list of dictionaries.
    result = [
        dict((char, 0) for char in chars)
        for position in range(max_position)
    ]

    # Count characters.
    for word in words:
        for position in range(len(word)):
            result[position][word[position]] += 1

    # Change to frequencies
    for position in range(max_position):
        count = sum(result[position].values())
        for char in chars:
            result[position][char] /= count  # float(count) for Python 2

    return result


# Testing
from pprint import pprint
mcode = ['AAB', 'AA', 'ABC', '']
pprint(freq(*mcode))
```

Result (Python 3):

```python
[{'A': 1.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0},
 {'A': 0.6666666666666666, 'B': 0.3333333333333333, 'C': 0.0},
 {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.5}]
```

In Python 3.6, the dictionaries are even sorted; earlier versions can use `OrderedDict` from `collections` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't efficient at all :

- You first need to define which letters you'd like to count
- You need to parse the string for each distinct letter

You could just use `Counter`:

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
mcode=['AAB', 'AA', 'ABC', '']
all_letters = set(''.join(mcode))

def freq(code):
  code = [letter for letter in code if letter is not None]
  n = len(code)
  counter = Counter(code)
  return {letter: counter[letter]/n for letter in all_letters}

print([freq(x) for x in itertools.zip_longest(*mcode)])
# [{'A': 1.0, 'C': 0.0, 'B': 0.0}, {'A': 0.6666666666666666, 'C': 0.0, 'B': 0.3333333333333333}, {'A': 0.0, 'C': 0.5, 'B': 0.5}]
```

For Python2, you could use `itertools.izip_longest`.