# how can I found the most repeated word and how much repeated it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts=dict() 
bigword=None
bigcount=None
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From:'):continue
    if line.startswith('From '):
        line=line.rstrip()
        x=line.split('From ')
        y=x[1]
        z=y.split()
        d=z[0]
        print(z[0])
```

ın the text there were many things and whit that it takes only 
user names such as 'sinemucari@gmail.com'
now I want to take all this names there were like 30 names. and put them in to dictionary and count how much they were repeated and what is the most repeated one.

```
    for user in z[0]: 
            counts[user]=counts.get(user,0)+1
            print(counts)
        for user,count in counts.items():
            if bigcount is None or count>bigcount:
               bigword=user
               bigcount=count
               print(bigcount,bigword)
```

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you were able to successfully create a dictionary that maps each word to its number of occurrences. Your goal is to find the word in the dictionary with the largest value and output that word and value.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510768/count-frequency-of-words-in-a-list-and-sort-by-frequency

Comment: no I have to use dictionaries. this is not solution. my code is not working if you like ı can share txt to. pls help me ı am very close to get crayz.