# Loop through multiple txt files and count frequencies of chosen word in Python

Tags: python, text-files, word-frequency

I have a exercise problem where I am asked to write a function that loops through 50 text files and counts the frequency of a chosen word in each text file. My code at the moment looks like this:

```JavaScript
def count(term):
    frequencies = 0
    
    work_dir = "C:/my_work_directory"
    for i in range(1, 51):
        name = "chapter-{i}.txt".format(i=i)
        path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
        with io.open(path, "r") as fd:
            content = fd.read()
    
        chapter = io.StringIO(content)
        line = chapter.readline()
        print(chapter)
        while line:
            lower = line.lower()
            cleaned = re.sub('[^a-z ]','', lower)
            words = cleaned.strip().split(' ')
            for word in words:
                if word == term:
                    frequencies += 1
            line = chapter.readline()
        
        print(frequencies)
```

The output I want is that, if I enter count("Man"), I get 50 different frequencies of how often the word "Man" came up in each text file. However, all I am getting at the moment is 50 zeros. I am fairly sure this is because I have initialised the variable 'frequencies' at 0 and then haven't done anything to it. Can anyone help me fix this issue or tell me where I am going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count frequency of words in a list and sort by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510768/count-frequency-of-words-in-a-list-and-sort-by-frequency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your 'Man' has a capital letter, and all your words are lower case. So the first thing would be to call the `lower()` function on the `term` variable. The second thing that is wrong, and you would only notice it later, is that you're keeping a running count, instead of a per-file count. So move the initialization of the frequency variable into the for loop. So it should look something like this.

```py
def count(term):
    term = term.lower()
    
    work_dir = "C:/my_work_directory"
    for i in range(1, 51):
        frequencies = 0

        name = "chapter-{i}.txt".format(i=i)
        path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
        with io.open(path, "r") as fd:
            content = fd.read()
    
        chapter = io.StringIO(content)
        line = chapter.readline()
        print(chapter)
        while line:
            lower = line.lower()
            cleaned = re.sub('[^a-z ]','', lower)
            words = cleaned.strip().split(' ')
            for word in words:
                if word == term:
                    frequencies += 1
            line = chapter.readline()
        
        print(frequencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

I runned it and it works fine after i change work_dir="" (So it looked at local). So i think you should check work directory path or assert if term parameter is correct