# Missing keys from dictionary counting words in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My output is incomplete. There are 3 element which don't count.

```
# A programm to count words in a string and put them in a dictionary as key = word and value = count

def word_in_str (S):
    dict_s = {}   # make a empty dict

    s = S.lower() # make string lowercase
    l = s.split() # split string into a list and separate theme by spase

    print (l)     # original list contain all words

    for word in l:
        counter = l.count (str(word)) 

        print (str(word))  # for testing the code, it's value = count
        print (counter)    # for testing the code, it's key = word

        dict_s[str(word)] = counter 

        l[:] = (value for value in l if value != str(word)) #delete the word after count it

        print (l)          # for testing the code, it's the list after deleting the word        

    print (dict_s)         # main print code, but there is no ('when', 'young', 'and') in result


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    word_in_str ('I am tall when I am young and I am short when I am old')
```

the output for this code is:

```
['i', 'am', 'tall', 'when', 'i', 'am', 'young', 'and', 'i', 'am', 'short', 'when', 'i', 'am', 'old']
i
4
['am', 'tall', 'when', 'am', 'young', 'and', 'am', 'short', 'when', 'am', 'old']
tall
1
['am', 'when', 'am', 'young', 'and', 'am', 'short', 'when', 'am', 'old']
am
4
['when', 'young', 'and', 'short', 'when', 'old']
short
1
['when', 'young', 'and', 'when', 'old']
old
1
['when', 'young', 'and', 'when'] <==what happened to this words?
{'i': 4, 'tall': 1, 'am': 4, 'short': 1, 'old': 1}  <==result without the words above
```

Comment: Try to format the output also as code to make it look properly. Distinguish more clearly what is real output, which part of it is wrong and what is expected.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `l[:] =` line to do?

Comment: You should not modify a list while iterating over it.

Comment: I would recommend to create a second list without duplicates first and then iterate over this list while modifying the original list.

Comment: Use correct upper case letter. Be more specific with your subject.

Comment: Check out: [Count frequency of words in a list and sort by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510768/count-frequency-of-words-in-a-list-and-sort-by-frequency)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over thinking the problem. A Counter already counts elements of an iterable, and it is a type of dict

```
from collections import Counter

def word_in_str(S):
    return dict(Counter(S.split()))
```

The problem with your code is that your for loop is over `l`, but then you're attempting to "delete" and reassign `l[:]`, where you don't really need to. Just count and store the dict entry.

Answer (score -1):

```
def word_in_str (S):
    dict_s = {}
    s = S.lower()
    l = s.split()
    for word in l:
        counter = l.count (word)
        dict_s[word] = counter 
    print (dict_s)
    
word_in_str ('I am tall when I am young and I am short when I am old')
```

Comment: You should check `if word not in dict_s` before finding the count and updating the dict. Otherwise, you're needlessly counting duplicates